# Send File with fetch, FormData API and multer : image won't upload

Tags: javascript, upload, fetch, multipartform-data, multer

I try to send some FormData in fetch body, to upload image with multer (nodeJS).

I tried to set a Header `"Content-Type": "multipart/form-data"` to my fetch call, but when I do that, I have a nodeJS error:

> Error: Multipart: Boundary not found

I tried then to remove the `Content-Type` header, so the browser set it by default, and the fetch fails, I even do not enter in my nodeJS router.

Here is my my FormData preparation method:

```js
handleChange = event =>
{
    if(event.target.type === 'file')
    {
        const files = event.target.files;
        var formData = new FormData();

        for(var i = 0; i < files.length; i++)
        {
            formData.append('images[]', files[i], files[i].name);
        }

        //UPLOAD IMAGE METHOD
        Image.upload(formData);
    }

};
```

Here is my fetch call:

```js
upload: async function(formData)
{
    return fetch('http://localhost:8080/image/upload', {
        method: 'post',
        body: formData
    })
}
```

and here is my controler:

```js
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const multer = require('multer');
const upload = multer({dest: __dirname + '/uploads/images'});

router.post('/upload', upload.array('images'), (req, res) => {
    console.log('req.file', req.file, req.files, req.body);
    return res.sendStatus(200);
});

module.exports = router;
```

previously routed by `app.use('/image', require('./controllers/imageController'));` so the url of access is http://localhost:8080/image/upload

response header without Content-Type:

```
Provisional headers are shown
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryi3lc9wCsnhrvAOAB
Origin: http://localhost:3000
Referer: http://localhost:3000/backoffice/catalog/edit/5d976d6b50fd7f3d008d0f16
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/77.0.3865.120 Safari/537.36
images[]: (binary)
```

error with Content-Type:

> Error: Multipart: Boundary not found

Thank you all for your brains :) !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally, I didn't look at the good place : It was the file I tried to upload that was corrupted. I tried with another one and it worked just fine.